# Limit number of server calls using a defined threshold

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm using [request-sync](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request) to get data from a specific site API, like this:

```
let req = request('GET', LINK, {
  'headers': {
    'Accept'                                          : ''
    'X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id' : '',
    'X-FirePHP-Version'                               : '',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests'                       : '',
    'User-Agent'                                      : '',
    'Referer'                                         : '',
    'Accept-Encoding'                                 : '',
    'Accept-Language'                                 : '',
    'Cookie'                                          : ''
  }
});
```

And i'm worry about the owners block my API or sue my if they release the quantity of requests that i'm doing.

So, i would like to block 50 requests per minute. That's possible? How so? There isn't a package to help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same using timers i.e. `window.setInterval`. Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

See below same example I have created for you. In this I am making maximum of 15 dummy server calls per 30 seconds, once threashold of 15 is reached, server calls will stop. Then once 30 seconds have elapsed, server calls will resume.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var count = 0;
            function makeServerCall(){
                console.log('making server call ... ' + count);
                count++;
            }

            function checkAndMakeServerCall(){
                if(count <= 15){  //Set how many calls you want to make within time set using setInterval(function(){ count = 0; }, 30000);
                    makeServerCall();
                } else{
                    console.log('not making server call ...');
                }
            }

            setInterval(function(){ checkAndMakeServerCall() }, 1000);
            setInterval(function(){ count = 0; }, 30000); //Define time... 30000 means 30 seconds ...

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>        
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-rate-limiter](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter) that do just that.

Another possibility is to use tor as a proxy for your application, so you don't have to worry about ip rate restriction.

An easy to use distribution of tor is [Vidalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidalia_(software)).